# Should localStorage persist when application is run via live server?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, local-storage, persistence

I am running an application via VSCode's [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension.

This application (e-commerce website) saves items to a cartItems array that gets written to localStorage whenever an addToCart button is clicked. I can see in DevTools/Application/LocalStorage that the items are being saved correctly when the specified actions are taken.

However, my localStorage is cleared whenever I refresh the page or navigate to a different page within the same application.

When writing items to localStorage, I have tried invoking the `localStorage` short-hand, as well as the more explicit `window.localStorage`. Neither has worked for this issue.

Does localStorage not persist when an application is run locally or via a live server? I suspect it should and I am doing something else incorrectly.

The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) mentions:

> The read-only `localStorage` property allows you to access a `Storage`
> object for the `Document`'s origin; the stored data is saved across
> browser sessions. `localStorage` is similar to `sessionStorage`, except
> that while data stored in `localStorage` has no expiration time, data
> stored in `sessionStorage` gets cleared when the page session ends —
> that is, when the page is closed. (Data in a `localStorage` object
> created in a "private browsing" or "incognito" session is cleared when
> the last "private" tab is closed.)

Could it be that each refresh or page change on live server represents an entirely new device history? (Again, this feels plausible but still unlikely. I am happy to be wrong, however.)

Thank you in advance for any guidance you can provide.

---

EDIT - Here is some of the relevant code:

In the global scope:

```
const cartItems = [];
localStorage.setItem('cartItemsKey', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey');
const cartItemsInStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey');
```

Encapsulated - this function fires when an addToCart button is clicked. Omitting most of it, except the part pertaining to `localStorage`, for brevity:

```
function addToCart (button) {
    // Create newCartItem object using relevant data
    cartItems.push(newCartItem);
        localStorage.removeItem('cartItemsKey');
        localStorage.setItem('cartItemsKey', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}
```

Again, I can see that the items are successfully being saved to localStorage, per the below screen recording. It's when I refresh or change pages that I have trouble.

[image: local-storage-issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:

I figured out what the issue was.

I have the following code in the global scope:

```
const cartItems = [];
localStorage.setItem('cartItemsKey', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey');
const cartItemsInStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey');
```

Which gets called before this code:

```
function addToCart (button) {
    // Create newCartItem object using relevant data
    cartItems.push(newCartItem);
        localStorage.removeItem('cartItemsKey');
        localStorage.setItem('cartItemsKey', JSON.stringify(cartItems));
}
```

So I was effectively re-writing an empty array into localStorage every time the page reloaded.

I have resolved this issue by removing the `.setItem` line as follows:

```
const cartItems = [];
localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey');
const cartItemsInStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey');
```

Now, I will rewrite my initial `const cartItems = [];` as a conditional statement, where I first check to see if cartItemsKey exists in global storage. If so, I will set `cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItemsKey')`. Otherwise, I will set `cartItems = [];`.

Thank you very much, @Alex Rasidakis, for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide us with some code? I don't think that the Live Server has anything
to do with the local storage malfunction you are talking about.

I'm pretty sure it's a browser issue. Maybe you are using hard refresh somehow
each time you are refreshing. Maybe you have some setting that clears the local storage or some browser extension that cleans your page every time you refresh.

Try to open your localhost address from another browser like Mozilla, Edge etc.
and tell us about its behaviour.

Comment: Yes, I will edit my initial question and add some code.

Regarding the browser, I run Brave by default. However, I just tried running the application (via live server) on Chrome and Firefox - I still had the same issue. 

I don't have any browser extensions.

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't somewhere any part of javascript code that does this work behind the scenes?
Try to search in your project for storage.clear();
or localStorage.clear(); . If you do find them and you don't want them to be there, remove them.

Comment: Just finished my edit above. I do have too lines in the `addToCart()` function above where I remove the item and then re-set it. However, even when I delete the `.removeItem()` call the issue still persists.